# How to keep header row always on top in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to keep header row visible on the top all the time while scrolling in excel.  How can it be done? I'm using excel 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the first cell in the row which is below your header row.

Under the **View tab**, on **Windows** group, Select **Freeze panes**.  From the drop down menu, select **Freeze panes option**
[image]